# Show that the center $\mathcal{Z}(G) =\{g \in G ∶ ga=ag \text{ for all a} \in G\}$ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I see help for showing $G/\mathcal{Z}(G)$ is abelian, but not $\mathcal{Z}(G)$. By definition isn't $\mathcal{Z}(G)$ abelian? How can I use the fact that $\mathcal{Z}(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$, because that is all I can think of to use.

Comment: Well, isn't the definition but is an inmediate consequence since if two points lie into the center, one conmutes with the other hence the operation in the center is conmutative.

Comment: By the way, $G/Z(G)$ is not abelian in general. For example $Z(GL_2(\mathbb{R}))=\mathbb{R}\mathrm{Id}_2$, and the quotient $G/Z(G)$ is the group $PGL_2(\mathbb{R})$, which is not abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centre of $G$ is the set of all elements of $G$ that commute with all other elements of $G$; in particular, these elements commute with all elements of the centre of $G$, since $\mathcal{Z}(G)\subseteq G$. Hence $\mathcal{Z}(G)$ is abelian.

Comment: Yes this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, @PhysicsBish :)

Answer (score 1):

$g \in Z$, $a \in Z \implies g \in Z$, $a \in G \implies ga=ag$.